# Converting pdf files to txt files but only getting last page of pdf file

Tags: python, for-loop, pdf, txt, pypdf

I'm trying to convert a list of PDF files in a directory to txt. At the moment, however, I'm only getting the last page of the pdf files in the newly created txt. files.

The code:

```
import os, PyPDF2
import re

for file in os.listdir("Documents/Python/"):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        fpath=os.path.join("Documents/Python/", file)
        pdffileobj=open(fpath,'rb')
        pdfreader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdffileobj)
        x=pdfreader.numPages
        pageobj=pdfreader.getPage(x-1)
        text=pageobj.extractText()
        newfpath=re.sub(".pdf","txt",fpath)
        file1=open(newfpath,"a")
        file1.writelines(text)
```

Txt files with all the pages

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the text of the last page because you are only ever reading the text of the last page of each pdf `pageobj=pdfreader.getPage(x-1)`

Although it works, it looks like  `pdfreader.numPages` is [deprecated](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfReader.html?highlight=numpages#PyPDF2.PdfReader.numPages) now. The way to do it is `len(reader.pages)` if you wanted the number of pages. You could also just loop through each page object without getting the number of pages `for page in pdfreader.pages:`

The main thing you are missing is a second loop to go through each page of the pdf and extract the text.

```
for file in os.listdir("/your/path"):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        fpath=os.path.join("/your/path", file)
        pdffileobj=open(fpath,'rb')
        pdfreader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdffileobj)
        newfpath=re.sub(".pdf",".txt",fpath)
        with open(newfpath,"w") as file:
            #loop through each page and write to file
            for page in pdfreader.pages:
                text=page.extractText()
                file.write(text)
```